# What is the Best RAID configuration for Hard Drives Varying in Sizes

Tags: raid, configuration, hard-drive, windows-server-2016

We will be rebuilding our server to run Windows Server 2016, with Hyper-V for 1 domain controller and 1 more VM for a NAS + Web Server.

However, we must first decide on our RAID configuration before proceeding.

We currently have 7 HDD which total 19TB of storage in the following sizes:

- 2 x 5TB
- 4 x 2TB
- 1 x 1TB

We have on-site and off-site replication so this RAID configuration's purpose will not be for a backup (as RAID is not a backup). What would be the most reliable and best way to install the Windows Server 2016 and RAID configure these drives of varying sizes?

Comment: You should shape your virtualization environment according to your needs and not according to what hardware is lying around...

Comment: @Zac67 Thanks! This is also taken into consideration. The NAS would ideally be given as much storage as possible as that is what the server is primarily used for and we are planning for future growth. The web server just provides a way of linking certain files types for staff within documents, so it doesn't need much storage at all.

Comment: What type is the RAID controller and what options does it offer?

Comment: @Zac67 it's a ThinkServer RAID 110i and can do RAID1, RAID0 or RAID10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, given what you've got there's not too much choice:

2x 5 TB in RAID1

4x 2 TB in RAID10

1x 1 TB as temp

Comment: Thanks for the help! I'm not a guru with RAID configuration, so could you please explain the reasoning/benefit behind the suggestions for me?

Comment: RAID0 is not an option when any availability is required. A pair of like disks can then only be put in RAID1. The two like 2 TB pairs can be striped (RAID0 over RAID1 = RAID10) for better performance. Putting the 4x 2TB in RAID5 would yield more capacity (6 instead of 4 TB) but isn't supported.